# Is there a way to model the error term in a linear regression with R?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares

I'm tryin to estimate a pretty basic regression. I have a dataset containing `x` and `y` and would like to esimate the following model in R

```
y = b0 + b1*x1 + b2*epsilon
```

where epsilon=error term. I'm trying the lm() function in R, but do not know how to include the error term in the regression. Does anyone know how to include the error term. Is there any good packages for R to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The error term is always included when fitting a regression. You just need to specify the non-random component of the model (b0 + b1*x1)

Comment: Yes, but I want to model the error term in the regression. Therefore I want to include it. For example y = b0 + b1*x1 + 30*epsilon

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is fixed, e.g. to mean 0 variance 1, then the $b_2$ estimate is what `lm` gives you as 'standard error' in the summary output, ie the conditional variance.  If it's not fixed then $b_2$ is not separately identified in $b_2\epsilon$ without more information.

Comment: you meant a mixed effects model? use `lmer` package.